# URL Rewritten and Cache control apache htaccess

Tags: caching, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page index.php which depending on the arguments provided generates different output.
Using mod_rewrite i have those files a a.htm, b.htm and c.htm .
Now, i want these particular 4 Files (or URLs actually) to be cached locally, 
for that i have tried

```
<FilesMatch "(a\.htm|b\.htm|c\.htm)$">
    FileETag None
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

But it doesn't work. 
how do we go about this issue ?

Comment: Can you show the mod_rewrite statements you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.htm index.php
<FilesMatch "index.htm">
    FileETag None
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is a sneak peak of what i have right now. But in the long run there will be lots of files and rewritten url's. so i want to add cache headers via htaccess . hope it makes sense !